# How to group data already group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query based in Objects as `"Ticket"` structure, each ticket usually contains Tasks Object and each of them have an Owner, if the Ticket is Open, the associate `Owner` is `“OpnPrps.CurAgtNme”`, by other hand if the ticket is Closed, the associate Owner is `“Nms.CloAgt”`.

This is how my database (JSON) look like:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(3131032306336),
            "TicId" : 1147552,
            "OrgId" : 729,
            "Sts" : "Closed",
            "CrtDat" : ISODate("2015-04-23T18:50:46.000Z"),
            "CloDat" : ISODate("2015-04-23T19:46:26.000Z"),
            "ShtDes" : "Copy of Employment agreement",
            "Des" : "EE wants a copy of employment agreement. address was verified.",
            "DesSum" : "EE wants a copy of employment agreement. address was verified.",
            "Sol" : "ISIGHT TICKET NUMBER:<br><h1>US-04-15-01109</h1>",
            "CrtAgtId" : 20444,
            "CloAgtId" : 20149,
            "CrtApp" : null,
            "IsInt" : false,
            "HasPrtTsk" : null,
            "PexBodId" : "",
            "PayGrp" : "",
            "RvwDat" : null,
            "RclDat" : null,
            "IsDynDueDatDef" : false,
            "OlaDat" : ISODate("2015-04-25T00:50:50.000Z"),
            "SlaDat" : ISODate("2015-04-25T00:50:50.000Z"),
            "DynDueDatElaDat" : null,
            "ReaTim" : "00:00:00",
            "LstUpd" : ISODate("2015-04-23T19:46:26.000Z"),
            "VrsOnl" : 2,
            "VrsArc" : 1,
            "OpnPrps" : null,
"Nms" : {
                "Cmp" : "Organization1 US",
                "Org" : "Organization1",
                "Srv" : "Policies",
                "SrvGrp" : "17. Workforce Administration (NGR)",
                "Wkg" : "WORKGROUP1",
                "Pri" : "",
                "Tir" : "T1",
                "Src" : "Call",
                "CrtAgt" : "Arun ",
                "CloAgt" : "Felicia"
            },
"Olas" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "EntNam" : "ENTITY",
                "DueDat" : ISODate("2015-04-25T00:50:50.000Z"),
                "AmbDat" : ISODate("2015-04-24T20:50:49.000Z"),
                "DueDatElaDat" : null,
                "AmbDatElaDat" : null,
                "SlaDuration" : 18,
                "TotTim" : NumberLong(0),
                "TotTimPndEnt" : NumberLong(0),
                "TotTimPndEmp" : NumberLong(0),
                "RclInSla" : false
            },
"Tsks" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Typ" : "Planned",
                "CrtDat" : ISODate("2015-04-23T18:50:46.000Z"),
                "CloDat" : null,
                "LstUpd" : ISODate("2015-04-23T18:50:46.000Z"),
                "DueDat" : ISODate("2015-04-25T00:50:50.000Z"),
                "TimCplTsk" : 1080,
                "DueDatEla" : false,
                "AgtOwnId" : null,
                "WkgSklId" : 45387,
                "EntId" : 2,
                "Sts" : "Open",
                "PrdTskId" : 201,
                "Ttl" : "Provide Navigational Assistance",
                "Des" : "Provide Navigational Assistance",
                "SrvSklId" : 45792,
                "PriSklId" : null,
                "TotTim" : 0,
                "PtnId" : null,
                "PtnTic" : null,
                "DepTskId" : null,
                "IsAct" : true,
                "IsMndOnCloTic" : false,
                "Nms" : {
                    "AgtOwn" : null,
                    "Wkg" : "CM_T1",
                    "Ent" : "ENTITY",
                    "SrvSkl" : "Policies",
                    "PriSkl" : null,
                    "Ptn" : null,
                    "Frm" : ""
                },
                "AscTicItm" : null,
                "FrmId" : null,
                "Flds" : []
            },
```

And the query I'm using to group the data looks like:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        'Nms.Org': 'Organization1',
        'Nms.Cmp':'Company',
        'Nms.Wkg':'Workgroup’

    }},
    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        'Tsks._id':1,
        'Tsks.Sts':1,
        'Tsks.DueDat':1,
        'Sts':1,
        'Nms.Org':1,
        'Nms.Cmp':1,
        'Nms.Wkg':1,
        'Nms.CloAgt':1,
        'OpnPrps.CurAgtNme':1, 
        'OpnPrps.CurEntNme':1,
        'Olas.EntNam':1
        }},

    {$unwind : "$Olas" },
    {$unwind : "$Tsks" },
    {$match:{$and:[{
        'Tsks.DueDat': {$ne: null},
        'Olas.EntNam': 'Entity',
        'Tsks._id':{$gt:0}
        }]}},

        {$group:
    {_id:{
                Org:'$Nms.Org',
                Cmp:'$Nms.Cmp',
                Wkg:'$Nms.Wkg',
                CurEntNme:'$Olas.EntNam', 
                CurTskId: '$Tsks._id',
                DueDate:'$Tsks.DueDat', 
                Owner1:'$OpnPrps.CurAgtNme', 
                Owner2:'$Nms.CloAgt'
                },
                All: {$sum: { $cond: 
                             [ 
                                {   $eq: [ '$Tsks.DueDat' , null ] } ,0,1
                             ]}}

            },

        }
    ])
```

With this query I’m able to get every ticket for every owner (even if they’re open or closed) and their associate tasks, my problem is that I want to group all the tickets without taking in consideration the status, something like a second group after the results I have now, see below:

The table I get with Jasper Studio with this query looks like:

```
Owner       Inventory   
---------   --------------
Noemi          1                   Owner1:Noemi | Owner2:null
Carl           2                   Owner1:null | Owner2:Carl
Darla          2                   Owner1:Darla| Owner2:null
Carl           1                   Owner1:Carl| Owner2:null
Paola          2                   Owner1:null| Owner2:Paola
Noemi          2                   Owner1:null | Owner2:Noemi
```

As you can see, I’m getting repeated values due to the different field from each ticket. The table I'm looking for should be like this:

```
 Owner       Inventory   
 ---------   --------------
 Noemi          3                   Owner1:Noemi | Owner2:Noemi
 Carl           3                   Owner1:Carl | Owner2:Carl
 Darla          2                   Owner1:Darla| Owner2:null
 Paola          2                   Owner1:null| Owner2:Paola
```

So, my problem is that I can’t find the way to group these results again to obtain the second table.

Comment: To get answers, people need a "clear" sample of the data you have now ( existing in collection ) and output that you want to get to. Your current aggregation pipeline mentions "arrays" to `$unwind` and other elements that are neither clearly defined or present in the proprietary schema example you are giving, which is not really relevant to solving the question. Please show some sample JSON formatted data and the results you want to ( and can be reproduced from the data given ) achieve. That will help you get answers.

Comment: I edited my code with a JSON example. Thanks.

Comment: Your aggregation pipline uses `$unwind`. If it works at all then the referenced fields must be arrays. There are no "arrays" in the data as shown. Also the "result" structure here points to this is either the "result" of an aggregation operation or mapReduce operation rather than a direct query to the collection. I asked for as everyone wants to see as well  "the original document structure" as it exists. Open a shell or other tool and `db.tickets.findOne()`

Comment: I can't share here one whole ticket structure because is very very heavy and I have not enough storage to show, also I'm working with a private database from a company and I'm not able to share real data.

Comment: Just the fields you want to use in the query though. Do some editing. The point is unless you give people "something" to work with then there is no clear way to get to your result. A clear sample gives A. a source that can be used to get to a result, and B. a result that can actually be derived from the initial sample.

Comment: I added some notes also at the end of the topic, hopefully you will be able to understand now my problem. Thank you!